# rdp file launched debugging and not on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdp

I want to launch a .rdp file from a webmethod. If I debugg the code I can see how the file is launched but once I upload the code to the iis server I the file is not launched.

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"mstsc.exe ", @"myconnection.rdp");

process.WaitForExit();
```

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you expecting the rdp to open? And even if you want it to open on the server you need more privileges than a default AppPool to launch programs on the server.

Comment: The rdp connects to a remote server in order to perform some operations there. The rdp itselfs opens a bat file on that server and It has parametrized the credendtials. The impersonated user of the pool has executing privileges. Thanks in advance,